# SQL - AND and OR Prededence

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, postgresql, oracle11g

I have a SQL query, I am a bit confused which conditions in the WHERE clause is executed first. Can you give me the steps which are involved when executing the WHERE clause .Here is my query.

```
select * from table where a='a' OR b='b' OR c='c' AND d='d';
```

Comment: When in doubt, use parenthesis `()`

Comment: Even if not in doubt, you should always use parenthesis when you are mixing `ANDs` and `ORs`

Answer (score 1):

This is operator precedence [list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

From Mysql Documentation

```
INTERVAL
BINARY, COLLATE
!
- (unary minus), ~ (unary bit inversion)
^
*, /, DIV, %, MOD
-, +
<<, >>
&
|
= (comparison), <=>, >=, >, <=, <, <>, !=, IS, LIKE, REGEXP, IN
BETWEEN, CASE, WHEN, THEN, ELSE
NOT
&&, AND
XOR
||, OR
= (assignment), :=
```

Hence **AND** has higher precedence than **OR**.

You need to push brackets for avoiding ambiguity. it will help the readability, but it'll work fine without them

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE a='a' OR b='b' OR (c='c' AND d='d');
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) docs:

`AND` has higher precedence so this will be evaluated first.

In general prefer to use braces to show precedence. This makes the query more readable:

```
select * from table where a='a' OR b='b' OR (c='c' AND d='d');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
select * from table where d='d' and (a='a' OR b='b' OR c='c');
```

Answer (score 0):

`AND` has high precedence over `OR`.

**Refer to**:
[*MySQL: Operator Precedence*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html)

> Operator precedences are shown in the following list, from highest precedence to the lowest. Operators that are shown together on a line have the same precedence.
>
> `&&, AND`
> `XOR`
> `||, OR`

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server , there is no fixed order of execution in WHERE clause. This is decided by [**SQL Query optimizer**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/02/22/60527.aspx) prior to creating an execution plan.

Ofcourse , you can force a particular order using parenthesis which is a recommended practice
when mixing multiple AND / OR conditions

Answer (score 0):

Yes Anand seems to be correct as you are asking SQL to return anything where B='b'but only show me the results if any of  a=a or b=b or c=c match then the:

WHERE d='d' clause need to come at the begging of your WHERE clause so:

```
select * from table where d='d' and (a='a' OR b='b' OR c='c');
```

will give you your required results.

Thanks